# Merging Text files in Different Folders in a Parent folder

Tags: cmd

I have 50 sub-Folders inside a Single Parent Folder.

Inside  each sub folders there are multiple .txt files. I want to merge all the text files in a single sub-folder into 1 .txt file.

But I want a command so that it can be done in one go for all the subfolder, like i don't want to write command for each sub-folder.

For example:-

ABCD (Parent Folder ):-
A
B ; Here A and B are sub-folder

A\0001.txt
A\0002.txt

I want to merge and make a single text file A\0001.txt.

B\0001.txt
B\0002.txt

I want to merge both the text files in B Folder.

Can it be done in one go ?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a lot easier using powershell.

Try the following and change the basedir to the parent folder of all your subdirectories.

```
$basedir = "C:\Basedir"
$folderlist = Get-childitem -Path $basedir
foreach ($folder in $folderlist)
{
$dir = $folder
$outFile = Join-Path $dir "merged.txt"
# Build the file list
$fileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter File*.txt -File
# Get the header info from the first file
Get-Content $fileList[0] | select -First 2 | Out-File -FilePath $outfile -Encoding ascii
# Cycle through and get the data (sans header) from all the files in the list
foreach ($file in $filelist)
{
Get-Content $file | select -Skip 2 | Out-File -FilePath $outfile -Encoding ascii -Append
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe old but useful: this version works with folders and subfolders recursively:

```
$basedir = "..."
$folderlist = Get-childitem -Path $basedir -Recurse -Directory | Select-Object FullName

foreach ($folder in $folderlist)
{
    Write-Host $folder.FullName
    $dir = $folder.FullName
    $outFile = Join-Path $basedir "merged.txt"
    # Build the file list
    $fileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter *.log | Select-Object FullName

    # Get the header info from the first file
    #Get-Content $fileList[0] | select -First 2 | Out-File -FilePath $outfile -Encoding ascii
    # Cycle through and get the data (sans header) from all the files in the list
    foreach ($file in $filelist)
    {
        Write-Host $file.FullName
        Get-Content $file.FullName | Out-File -FilePath $outfile -Encoding ascii -Append
    }
}
```